# Por que não consigo chamar objeto cta1 instanciado em btnCriarConta_Click?

Tags: c#

Por que não consigo chamar objeto `cta1` instanciado em `btnCriarConta_Click`?

```
namespace proj3 {
   public partial class conta : System.Web.UI.Page {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      }
      protected void btnCriarConta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         try {
            decimal saldo = decimal.Parse(txtSaldo.Text);
            ContaBancaria cta1 = new ContaBancaria(1, saldo);
            Session.Add("conta", cta1);
            msgGeral.Text = "Conta criada com sucesso.";
         }catch (Exception ex){
         }
      }
      protected void btnDebitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         try {
            cta1.debitar(decimal.Parse(txtSaldo.Text));
         } catch (Exception ex) {
         }
      }
      protected void btnCreditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         try {
         }catch (Exception ex) {
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Onde está o JavaScript nesse código?

Answer (score 1):

O trecho que código que você adicionou não é javascript, eu acho que é c#.

Você não consegue acessar `cta1` por causa do escopo, a variável só existe dentro do corpo do método `btnCriarConta_Click`.

Para poder utilizar o objeto dentro de `btnDebitar_Click` você pode obter ele através do `Session` utilizando a chave "conta" já que após criar a `ContaBancaria` você salva ela na sessão do usuário.

Uma outra solução que não tenho certeza se atende seu caso seria definir a conta como um propriedade da classe `conta` e acessar essa propriedade em `btnCriarConta_Click` e `btnDebitar_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

Porque a variável foi criada (portanto, está limitada) ao escopo da função.

Ou seja, a **variável** `cta1` é criada em `btnCriarConta_Click` e somente acessível a partir desta função (após sua declaração).

Por outro lado, você está salvando o **objeto** (conteúdo da variável) no estado da sessão.

Basicamente, o que falta é declarar uma variável de mesmo tipo na função desejada para obter o objeto salvo na sessão, e então chamar o método desejado.

```
protected void btnDebitar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     try 
     {
        ContaBancaria cta1 = (ContaBancaria) Session["conta"]; // Aqui!
        cta1.debitar(decimal.Parse(txtSaldo.Text));
     } 
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
     }
}
```